# Is Torch7 defined-by-run like Pytorch?

Tags: python, lua, torch, pytorch

Pytorch have Dynamic Neural Networks (defined-by-run) as opposed to Tensorflow which have to compile the computation graph before run.

I see that both Torch7 and PyTorch depend on TH, THC, THNN, THCUNN (C library). Does Torch7 have Dynamic Neural Networks (defined-by-run) feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Torch7 use static computational graphs, as in Tensorflow. It is one of the major differences between PyTorch and Torch7.